# When to Persist Object Graph

Tags: ios, persistence

I have an object graph which represents the state of my (first) iOS app.  I've implemented NSCoding for each of the objects so I can use a keyed archiver.  I have the archiving and dearchiving working fine.  But I'm left with a rather basic question:  **When should I archive things?**

Is it safe to only call it when I get an *applicationDidEnterBackground* message from my app delegate? Or should I pesist things everytime the user does something "significant" in the interface (like dismiss some view where data was entered, etc.)?  What are the best practices for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question in this document:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html

Here is the relevant quote:

Important: Always save user data at appropriate checkpoints in your app. Although you can use app state transitions to force objects to write unsaved changes to disk, never wait for an app state transition to save data. For example, a view controller that manages user data should save its data when it is dismissed.